# Getting missing required positional arguments if passing *args with None values to a namedtuple object

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following case, when I pass the tuple `*values` to `Query()` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __new__() missing 9 required positional arguments: 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col7', 'col9', 'col11', 'col12', and 'col14'
```

```py
def map_value_to_column(values: tuple, columns: list) -> namedtuple:
    Query = namedtuple("Query", columns)
    return Query(*values)
```

Obviously this is happening because some of the values are `None`.  The problem here is that `values` is an immutable tuple and I don't want to copy all of the values to a list so I can map `None` to something else and I haven't found any other way to avoid this error. Is there a way I can make `Query(*values)` work in this case even if I have `None` values?

**Note**: I'm absolutely sure that the amount of values equals the amount of columns. Only some of the values can be `None`.

Comment: "Obviously this is happening because some of the values are `None`" that should not make any difference. If `values` contains nine items and `columns` too, you should be able to create the named tuple with the nine items, `None` or not. Do `print(len(values))` and `print(len(columns))` produce the same result?

Comment: it should work. post the actual `values` and `columns` content

Comment: The problem was in another part of my code, I'm absolutely wrong here. I was looking what the problem was for 1 hour before asking this question, and I found the answer just after that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in another part of my code.

I was passing a list of tuples instead of a single tuple to the function `map_value_to_column`.

I just needed to build a list and convert each tuple to a namedtuple inside:

```
def map_value_to_column(values: list, columns: list) -> namedtuple:
    Query = namedtuple("Query", columns)
    queries = []
    for value in values:
        queries.append(Query(*value))
    return queries
```

There is **no** problem with supplying `None` type arguments to `namedtuple`.